# How to open a iOS Native Page using URL Scheme on IBM Worklight?

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, native, url-scheme

I need to detect a URL Scheme call and if this call happen I need to start a native page.

By now, I've managed to build the URL scheme detection but how can I load my view and not IBM Worklight webview?

In the AppDelegate implementation I have these methods:

```
    // This method is called after the WL web framework initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.

-(void)wlInitWebFrameworkDidCompleteWithResult (WLWebFrameworkInitResult *)result {
    if ([result statusCode] == WLWebFrameworkInitResultSuccess) {
        [self wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully]; //declared below
    } else {
        [self wlInitDidFailWithResult:result];
    }
}

-(void)wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully {
    UIViewController* rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

    // Create a Cordova View Controller
    CDVViewController* cordovaViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init] ;

    cordovaViewController.startPage = [[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath];
    cordovaViewController.webView.scrollView.bounces = YES;

    // Adjust the Cordova view controller view frame to match its parent view bounds
    cordovaViewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.bounds;

    // Display the Cordova view
    [rootViewController addChildViewController:cordovaViewController];
    [rootViewController.view addSubview:cordovaViewController.view];
}
```

My idea is conditionate the call of this method with my other method, but the problem is that the **handleOpenURL** method is called after **wlInitWebFrameworkDidCompleteWithResult**'s call.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should review the following tutorial, which explains how you can "take control" over the startup flow of a Hybrid application. The tutorial is adjusted for MobileFirst apps, and you're using Worklight (an older release of MobileFirst) so you may need to further adjust it for your specific application implementation in the viewcontroller: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/adding-native-functionality/ios-adding-native-ui-elements-hybrid-applications/